# Query parameter And Url Rewriting And Url Blocking

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

On my site, only few query query parameters are allowed. Some Parameters are such that their length should be only 1 char i.e. A-Z or a-z or 1-0, but, some scanners or hackers trying to access url with lengthy parameters which my php application doesn't support, I can block them in php application level, by validating $_GET parameters, but my server is getting loaded, so I want to show 403/404 if parameters are not valid

example the correct UR::

```
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=A
```

but Getting

```
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=response.write(9687913*9040912
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=/.././.././.././.././.././.././.././../etc/./passwd%2500
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=%22%2bconvert(int%2cCHAR(52)%2bCHAR(67)%2bCHAR(117)%2bCHAR(84)%2bCHAR(117)%2bCHAR(79)%2bCHAR(115)%2bCHAR(84)%2bCHAR(107)%2bCHAR(68)%2bCHAR(76))%2b%22
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
http://example.com/books/index.php?cat=CWS%07%0e000x%9c%3d%8d1N%c3%40%10E%df%ae%8d%bdI%08)%d3%40%1d%a0%a2%05%09%11%89HiP%22%05D%8bF%8e%0bG%26%1b%d9%8e%117%a0%a2%dc%82%8a%1br%04X;%21S%8c%fe%cc%9b%f9%ff%aa%cb7Jq%af%7f%ed%f2.%f8%01>%9e%18p%c9c%9al%8b%aczG%f2%dc%beM%ec%abdkj%1
```

Is it possible to in .htaccess to restrict some parameters to accept only 1 character otherwise show 404 to users

Comment: Sure that’s possible … You have access to the query string contents via `%{QUERY_STRING}`, so all you need to do is write an according condition in a RewriteCond. The following RewriteRule can then deny access, if the condition matches.

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you want to restrict parameter `cat` to be just single letter then use this rule to return `403` error for all other cases of `cat` value:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)cat=[a-z](?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: it includes a-z what about A-Z and 0-9 and other special characters. As I don't know about regular expression

Comment: Due to `NC` it already covers `[A-Z]`. If you want to include `[0-9]` also then it would be: `[a-z\d]`. Apart from this any other character you want to allow?

Comment: Or if you want to allow only one char of anything then use: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)cat=\S(?:&|$)` where `\S` matches any non-space character.